# systemd service works different then running the .sh file from user shell trying run a VNC startup script with noVNC

Tags: linux, systemd

I want to run a .sh file with a systemd service. Let's explain it a little bit. If I go to `cd /home/ubuntu` I can run `./vnc_startup.sh`. This file creates a VNC connection and starts noVNC. Then I go to the browser open the address and login. I can run every command like as example `rosrun rviz rviz` because I have installed ROS.

If I use this service, it will not work:

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/novnc.service
[Unit]
After=NetworkManager.service time-sync.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu
TimeoutStartSec=infinity
TimeoutStopSec=infinity

ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/no_vnc_startup.log
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/vnc_startup.log
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/wm.log
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/wm_startup.log

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "source /etc/environment; /home/ubuntu/vnc_startup.sh"

ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/no_vnc_startup.log
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/vnc_startup.log
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/wm.log
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/wm_startup.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I also tried it with `systemctl --user start novnc.service` and put the file inside `/usr/lib/systemd/user` instead of `sudo systemctl start novnc.service` and `/etc/systemd/system/novnc.service`.

Following workaround will work in the noVNC environment: I can open a Terminal. I can see `ubuntu@hostname:~$`. So it seems to be the right user and I am in the right working directory. Before running as example `rosrun rviz rviz` I have to run `sudo su ubuntu`. And then it works. If I had run `./vnc_startup.sh` instead of running this script with systemd it works directly without the workaround with `sudo su ubuntu`.

Hard to explain. I hope you can understand me.

```
systemctl --user show-environment
HOME=/home/ubuntu
LANG=de_DE
LOGNAME=ubuntu
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=ubuntu
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001
```

The command `printenv` makes clear that maybe the `DISPLAY=:0` is missing, so I tried it with adding

```
export DISPLAY=:0
xset q
```

And I also added `Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/ubuntu/.Xauthority`:

```
[Unit]
After=NetworkManager.service time-sync.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/ubuntu/.Xauthority
TimeoutStartSec=infinity
TimeoutStopSec=infinity

ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/no_vnc_startup.log
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/vnc_startup.log
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/wm.log
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/wm_startup.log

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "source /etc/environment; export DISPLAY=:0; xset q; /home/ubuntu/vnc_startup.sh"

ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/no_vnc_startup.log
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/vnc_startup.log
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/wm.log
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /home/ubuntu/wm_startup.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here my log files:

```
cat no_vnc_startup.log

New 'shlServer01:1 (ubuntu)' desktop is shlServer01:1

Starting applications specified in /home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/ubuntu/.vnc/shlServer01:1.log

r settings:
  - Listen on :6901
  - Flash security policy server
  - Web server. Web root: /home/ubuntu/noVNC
  - No SSL/TLS support (no cert file)
  - proxying from :6901 to localhost:5901


Navigate to this URL:

    http://shlServer01:6901/vnc.html?host=shlServer01&port=6901

Press Ctrl-C to exit


192.168.0.6 - - [15/Dec/2021 15:16:56] 192.168.0.6: Plain non-SSL (ws://) WebSocket connection
192.168.0.6 - - [15/Dec/2021 15:16:56] 192.168.0.6: Version hybi-13, base64: 'False'
192.168.0.6 - - [15/Dec/2021 15:16:56] 192.168.0.6: Path: '/websockify'
192.168.0.6 - - [15/Dec/2021 15:16:56] connecting to: localhost:5901


cat vnc_startup.log
Killing Xvnc process ID 63164
Xvnc process ID 63164 already killed


cat wm.log
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :0
xfce4-session: Cannot open display: .
▒xfce4-session --help▒ eingeben, um mehr ▒ber die Verwendung zu erfahren.

cat wm_startup.log

------------------ startup of Xfce4 window manager ------------------
No protocol specified
xset:  unable to open display ":0"
No protocol specified
xset:  unable to open display ":0"
No protocol specified
xset:  unable to open display ":0"
No protocol specified
xrdb: Resource temporarily unavailable
xrdb: Can't open display ':0'
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :0
xfce4-session: Cannot open display: .
▒xfce4-session --help▒ eingeben, um mehr ▒ber die Verwendung zu erfahren.
```

What surprises me is that this is not the error. The error messages also come when I start the script from the terminal and then it works.

The vnc_startup.sh looks like following:

```
#!/bin/bash
### every exit != 0 fails the script
set -e

## print out help
help (){
echo "
OPTIONS:
-w, --wait      (default) keeps the UI and the vncserver up until SIGINT or SIGTERM will received
-s, --skip      skip the vnc startup and just execute the assigned command.
                example: docker run consol/centos-xfce-vnc --skip bash
-d, --debug     enables more detailed startup output
                e.g. 'docker run consol/centos-xfce-vnc --debug bash'
-h, --help      print out this help

Fore more information see: https://github.com/ConSol/docker-headless-vnc-container
"
}
if [[ $1 =~ -h|--help ]]; then
    help
    exit 0
fi

# should also source /home/ubuntu/generate_container_user
source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc

# add `--skip` to startup args, to skip the VNC startup procedure
if [[ $1 =~ -s|--skip ]]; then
    echo -e "\n\n------------------ SKIP VNC STARTUP -----------------"
    echo -e "\n\n------------------ EXECUTE COMMAND ------------------"
    echo "Executing command: '${@:2}'"
    exec "${@:2}"
fi
if [[ $1 =~ -d|--debug ]]; then
    echo -e "\n\n------------------ DEBUG VNC STARTUP -----------------"
    export DEBUG=true
fi

## correct forwarding of shutdown signal
cleanup () {
    kill -s SIGTERM $!
    exit 0
}
trap cleanup SIGINT SIGTERM

## write correct window size to chrome properties
/home/ubuntu/chrome-init.sh

## resolve_vnc_connection
VNC_IP=$(hostname -i)

## change vnc password
echo -e "\n------------------ change VNC password  ------------------"
# first entry is control, second is view (if only one is valid for both)
mkdir -p "/home/ubuntu/.vnc"
PASSWD_PATH="/home/ubuntu/.vnc/passwd"

if [[ -f $PASSWD_PATH ]]; then
    echo -e "\n---------  purging existing VNC password settings  ---------"
    rm -f $PASSWD_PATH
fi

if [[ $VNC_VIEW_ONLY == "true" ]]; then
    echo "start VNC server in VIEW ONLY mode!"
    #create random pw to prevent access
    echo $(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 20) | vncpasswd -f > $PASSWD_PATH
fi
echo "ubuntu" | vncpasswd -f >> $PASSWD_PATH
chmod 600 $PASSWD_PATH


## start vncserver and noVNC webclient
echo -e "\n------------------ start noVNC  ----------------------------"
if [[ $DEBUG == true ]]; then echo "/home/ubuntu/noVNC/utils/launch.sh --vnc localhost:5901 --listen 6901"; fi
/home/ubuntu/noVNC/utils/launch.sh --vnc localhost:5901 --listen 6901 &> /home/ubuntu/no_vnc_startup.log &
PID_SUB=$!

echo -e "\n------------------ start VNC server ------------------------"
echo "remove old vnc locks to be a reattachable container"
vncserver -kill :1 &> /home/ubuntu/vnc_startup.log \
    || rm -rfv /tmp/.X*-lock /tmp/.X11-unix &> /home/ubuntu/vnc_startup.log \
    || echo "no locks present"

echo -e "start vncserver with param: VNC_COL_DEPTH=24, VNC_RESOLUTION=1280x1024\n..."
if [[ $DEBUG == true ]]; then echo "vncserver :1 -depth 24 -geometry 1280x1024"; fi
vncserver :1 -depth 24 -geometry 1280x1024 &> /home/ubuntu/no_vnc_startup.log
echo -e "start window manager\n..."
/home/ubuntu/wm_startup.sh &> /home/ubuntu/wm_startup.log

## log connect options
echo -e "\n\n------------------ VNC environment started ------------------"
echo -e "\nVNCSERVER started on DISPLAY= :1 \n\t=> connect via VNC viewer with $VNC_IP:5901"
echo -e "\nnoVNC HTML client started:\n\t=> connect via http://$VNC_IP:6901/?password=...\n"


if [[ $DEBUG == true ]] || [[ $1 =~ -t|--tail-log ]]; then
    echo -e "\n------------------ /home/ubuntu/.vnc/*:1.log ------------------"
    # if option `-t` or `--tail-log` block the execution and tail the VNC log
    tail -f /home/ubuntu/*.log /home/ubuntu/.vnc/*:1.log
fi

if [ -z "$1" ] || [[ $1 =~ -w|--wait ]]; then
    wait $PID_SUB
else
    # unknown option ==> call command
    echo -e "\n\n------------------ EXECUTE COMMAND ------------------"
    echo "Executing command: '$@'"
    exec "$@"
fi
```

The wm_startup.sh looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
### every exit != 0 fails the script
set -e

echo -e "\n------------------ startup of Xfce4 window manager ------------------"

### disable screensaver and power management
xset -dpms &
xset s noblank &
xset s off &

/usr/bin/startxfce4 --replace > /home/ubuntu/wm.log &
sleep 1
cat /home/ubuntu/wm.log
```

And it should not be important but the launch.sh file fom noVNC looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Copyright 2016 Joel Martin
# Copyright 2016 Solly Ross
# Licensed under MPL 2.0 or any later version (see LICENSE.txt)

usage() {
    if [ "$*" ]; then
        echo "$*"
        echo
    fi
    echo "Usage: ${NAME} [--listen PORT] [--vnc VNC_HOST:PORT] [--cert CERT] [--ssl-only]"
    echo
    echo "Starts the WebSockets proxy and a mini-webserver and "
    echo "provides a cut-and-paste URL to go to."
    echo
    echo "    --listen PORT         Port for proxy/webserver to listen on"
    echo "                          Default: 6080"
    echo "    --vnc VNC_HOST:PORT   VNC server host:port proxy target"
    echo "                          Default: localhost:5900"
    echo "    --cert CERT           Path to combined cert/key file"
    echo "                          Default: self.pem"
    echo "    --web WEB             Path to web files (e.g. vnc.html)"
    echo "                          Default: ./"
    echo "    --ssl-only            Disable non-https connections."
    echo "                                    "
    exit 2
}

NAME="$(basename $0)"
REAL_NAME="$(readlink -f $0)"
HERE="$(cd "$(dirname "$REAL_NAME")" && pwd)"
PORT="6080"
VNC_DEST="localhost:5900"
CERT=""
WEB=""
proxy_pid=""
SSLONLY=""

die() {
    echo "$*"
    exit 1
}

cleanup() {
    trap - TERM QUIT INT EXIT
    trap "true" CHLD   # Ignore cleanup messages
    echo
    if [ -n "${proxy_pid}" ]; then
        echo "Terminating WebSockets proxy (${proxy_pid})"
        kill ${proxy_pid}
    fi
}

# Process Arguments

# Arguments that only apply to chrooter itself
while [ "$*" ]; do
    param=$1; shift; OPTARG=$1
    case $param in
    --listen)  PORT="${OPTARG}"; shift            ;;
    --vnc)     VNC_DEST="${OPTARG}"; shift        ;;
    --cert)    CERT="${OPTARG}"; shift            ;;
    --web)     WEB="${OPTARG}"; shift            ;;
    --ssl-only) SSLONLY="--ssl-only"             ;;
    -h|--help) usage                              ;;
    -*) usage "Unknown chrooter option: ${param}" ;;
    *) break                                      ;;
    esac
done

# Sanity checks
which netstat >/dev/null 2>&1 \
    || die "Must have netstat installed"

netstat -ltn | grep -qs ":${PORT} .*LISTEN" \
    && die "Port ${PORT} in use. Try --listen PORT"

trap "cleanup" TERM QUIT INT EXIT

# Find vnc.html
if [ -n "${WEB}" ]; then
    if [ ! -e "${WEB}/vnc.html" ]; then
        die "Could not find ${WEB}/vnc.html"
    fi
elif [ -e "$(pwd)/vnc.html" ]; then
    WEB=$(pwd)
elif [ -e "${HERE}/../vnc.html" ]; then
    WEB=${HERE}/../
elif [ -e "${HERE}/vnc.html" ]; then
    WEB=${HERE}
elif [ -e "${HERE}/../share/novnc/vnc.html" ]; then
    WEB=${HERE}/../share/novnc/
else
    die "Could not find vnc.html"
fi

# Find self.pem
if [ -n "${CERT}" ]; then
    if [ ! -e "${CERT}" ]; then
        die "Could not find ${CERT}"
    fi
elif [ -e "$(pwd)/self.pem" ]; then
    CERT="$(pwd)/self.pem"
elif [ -e "${HERE}/../self.pem" ]; then
    CERT="${HERE}/../self.pem"
elif [ -e "${HERE}/self.pem" ]; then
    CERT="${HERE}/self.pem"
else
    echo "Warning: could not find self.pem"
fi

# try to find websockify (prefer local, try global, then download local)
if [[ -e ${HERE}/websockify ]]; then
    WEBSOCKIFY=${HERE}/websockify/run

    if [[ ! -x $WEBSOCKIFY ]]; then
        echo "The path ${HERE}/websockify exists, but $WEBSOCKIFY either does not exist or is not executable."
        echo "If you intended to use an installed websockify package, please remove ${HERE}/websockify."
        exit 1
    fi

    echo "Using local websockify at $WEBSOCKIFY"
else
    WEBSOCKIFY=$(which websockify 2>/dev/null)

    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "No installed websockify, attempting to clone websockify..."
        WEBSOCKIFY=${HERE}/websockify/run
        git clone https://github.com/novnc/websockify ${HERE}/websockify

        if [[ ! -e $WEBSOCKIFY ]]; then
            echo "Unable to locate ${HERE}/websockify/run after downloading"
            exit 1
        fi

        echo "Using local websockify at $WEBSOCKIFY"
    else
        echo "Using installed websockify at $WEBSOCKIFY"
    fi
fi

echo "Starting webserver and WebSockets proxy on port ${PORT}"
#${HERE}/websockify --web ${WEB} ${CERT:+--cert ${CERT}} ${PORT} ${VNC_DEST} &
${WEBSOCKIFY} ${SSLONLY} --web ${WEB} ${CERT:+--cert ${CERT}} ${PORT} ${VNC_DEST} &
proxy_pid="$!"
sleep 1
if ! ps -p ${proxy_pid} >/dev/null; then
    proxy_pid=
    echo "Failed to start WebSockets proxy"
    exit 1
fi

echo -e "\n\nNavigate to this URL:\n"
if [ "x$SSLONLY" == "x" ]; then
    echo -e "    http://$(hostname):${PORT}/vnc.html?host=$(hostname)&port=${PORT}\n"
else
    echo -e "    https://$(hostname):${PORT}/vnc.html?host=$(hostname)&port=${PORT}\n"
fi

echo -e "Press Ctrl-C to exit\n\n"

wait ${proxy_pid}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to simply your `/etc/systemd/system/novnc.service` service unit with a single script for `ExecStart` command and a single script for `ExecStop`

#### `/etc/systemd/system/novnc.service`

```
[Unit]
After=NetworkManager.service time-sync.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/ubuntu/.Xauthority
TimeoutStartSec=infinity
TimeoutStopSec=infinity

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/home/ubuntu/servic_vnc_startup.sh"

ExecStop=/bin/bash -c "/home/ubuntu/servic_vnc_shutdown.sh"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### `/home/ubuntu/servic_vnc_startup.sh`

```
#!\bin\bash
source /home/ubuntu/.bash_profile
source /etc/environment
export DISPLAY=:0
xset q;
rm -f /home/ubuntu/{no_vnc_startup.log,vnc_startup.log,wm.log,wm_startup.log} 
/home/ubuntu/vnc_startup.sh
```

#### `/home/ubuntu/servic_vnc_shutdown.sh`

```
#!\bin\bash
source /home/ubuntu/.bash_profile
source /etc/environment
export DISPLAY=:0
xset q;
pkill -9 -f "/home/ubuntu/vnc_startup.sh"
rm -f /home/ubuntu/{no_vnc_startup.log,vnc_startup.log,wm.log,wm_startup.log}
```

#### Debugging

Login as user ubuntu.

Run `/home/ubuntu/servic_vnc_startup.sh` from command line.
If fails, fix it till it is successful.

Then try running `/home/ubuntu/servic_vnc_startup.sh`  as user noboby:

```
  sudo -u nobody "/home/ubuntu/servic_vnc_startup.sh"
```

User nobody has no shell and no environment context, as is the systemd service `/etc/systemd/system/novnc.service`.

If user nobody can run `/home/ubuntu/servic_vnc_startup.sh` then the `/etc/systemd/system/novnc.service` service unit can do as well.

Do same testing pattern with `/home/ubuntu/servic_vnc_shutdown.sh`

##### Lessons to learn:

1. Simplify service unit as much as possible.
2. Pull all scripting to a single shell script. Debug single shell script.
3. Avoid debugging handling service unit once deployed. Instead debug and modify called script.
4. Use user `nobody` user, to debug script to run without environment context and without shell.